# Inflating map view showing empty grid

Tags: android

I am trying to inflate my mapview like this

```
   ViewGroup mapLayout = (ViewGroup) View.inflate(mActivity, R.layout.details_map, null);
    mMapView = (MapView) mapLayout.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(mActivity);

    mMapView.onCreate(null);
```

the mapview shows but doesn't load the map tilts instead displays a empty grid

```
mMapView.onCreate(null);
```

I don't have the SavedInstanceState readily available can I not pass null here?
is there away to load it with out the SavedInstanceState.

Note I can't use the MapFragment cause it is already nested in a view pager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the docs again. It says you must call these methods your self on the MapView

```
onCreate(Bundle)
onResume()
onPause()
onDestroy()
onSaveInstanceState()
onLowMemory()
```

i got away with just calling once

```
mapView.onCreate(null)
mapView.onResume()
```